# PHPExcel me da error al agregar include/require a otros archivos

Tags: phpexcel

Basándome del siguiente ejemplo de [codedrinks](http://www.codedrinks.com/crear-un-reporte-en-excel-con-php-y-mysql/)
para crear un archivo excel con data que traigo de BD logro que todo me salga bien ,se crea el excel y logro abrirlo sin problemas, el código de ejemplo tiene un único

```
require_once 'lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
```

que es la llamada a la librería en cuestión, pero por ejemplo, si agrego otra sentencia de este tipo (include,include_once,reuire,etc.), en mi caso,

```
include("global.php");
```

Se descarga el archivo creado solo que al abrirlo muestar el siguiente error

> Excel no puede abrir el archivo [*nombre del archivo*] porque el
>   formato o la extensión de este no son válidos.Compruebe que el archivo
>   no se ha dañado y que la extensión del mismo coincide con el formato
>   del archivo.

Esto solo pasa cuando adiciono un `include` o cualquier sentencia de este tipo, y bueno me parece ilógico que no puede agregar una llamada a un archivo aparte del de la librería de PHPExcel.

Comment: Habría que ver que hay en el *global.php*, puede que esté modificando el header del response enviado al cliente.

Comment: No es necesario el codigo del global.php,lo que quiero indicar es que cualquier include o sentencia parecida adicional al include que se invoca para el PHP Excel da error.

Comment: Al menos pon en cuál lugar colocas el include y asegúranos que lo que incluye no inicia un reponse. Recuerda que al hacer un include si se produce algún warning o incluso errores el código continúa ejecutandose... De igual modo, deberíás colocar la generación del excel y el envío del response en una clase separada, de tal forma que sólo le pases los datos a incluir y el realice el envío la respuesta.

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolver el error?, tengo el mismo problema ahora :(

Answer (score 0):

A mí me funciono con require_once

algo así

```
require_once "menu.php";
```

si no te funciona intenta dejarlo en el mismo directorio donde está el archivo donde lo llamas.